# SQL query breaks when new table added

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database which handles information about what passes have been issued to who. When someone loses a pass, it is reissued, but recorded as the second issue.

I'm trying to write a query of every pass which has been issued, and if it needs to be hotlisted.

I've got it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed700/4

But when I try to add employee name to the query, it breaks (says there is an unknown column in the 'on' clause): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed700/6 (lines 3, 15 and 25 have been added)

I've no idea what's causing this..

P.S. This is a simplified version of the database structure to make it easier to post.

Comment: the second fiddle provided states `Unknown column 'PassProcessing.Passes_ID' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Yes, sorry; should have said that.

Comment: Weirdly when I change it to `INNER JOIN` it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed700/8

Comment: Fiddles are great, but SO requires that each question be able to stand on its own.  Please include the relevant query in your actual question.

Comment: Also it works when you change the `join` **order** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed700/9

Answer (score 5):

It is not good practice to mix ansi Joins and non-ansi Joins. Query can be re-written as:

```
SELECT
  PassProcessing.Serial AS Serial,
  Passes.Type AS CardType,
  PassProcessing.Issue AS IssueNumber,
  Employees.Name,
  (CASE WHEN sub.count > PassProcessing.Issue
   OR PassProcessing.Cancelled = 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
  END) AS Hotlist

FROM Passes
JOIN PassProcessing ON Passes.ID = PassProcessing.Passes_ID
JOIN Employees ON Passes.Employee_ID = Employees.ID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Passes_ID, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM PassProcessing
  GROUP BY Passes_ID) sub
  ON PassProcessing.Passes_ID = sub.Passes_ID
```

The exact reason can be found [on this page.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements
>   that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.

Comment: Can you please explain why OP's second query isn't working. Also it is not same as OP's query. `Employees` table should be joined with `INNER JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: +1 For finding a documentation on this, adding a link as well  would be better. Also, you should use `INNER JOIN` to `Employees` table.

Comment: @GavinCattell - As sagi mentioned +1 for doc. Edited the answer for correctness of the query. Hope you don't mind

Comment: @sagi Link should be more visible now.

Comment: Oh I missed that link. Guess I'm getting tired :S

Comment: There is no excuse at all for ever using implicit joins.